# how to define this variable "usersWithSecret is not defined" in app.js?

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
app.get('/secrets', function(req, res){

User.find({'secret': {$ne: null}}, function(err, foundUser){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
} else{
  if(foundUser){
    res.render('secrets', {usersWithSecret: usersWithSecret});
  }
}
});
});

  <%usersWithSecret.forEach(function(user){ %>
  <p class="secret-text"><%=user.secret%></p>
<% }) %>
```

The "userWithSecret" comes as not defined every time I run this code. How can I defined or declare this variable? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ejs template engine and here this is not how express.js works, you have rendered a view name secrets using below code

```
 res.render('secrets', {usersWithSecret: usersWithSecret});
```

so you can access usersWithSecret varibale inside secrets.ejs file obviously which you need to create(just create a file named secrets.ejs inside views folder) and then the below code will work there

```
 <%usersWithSecret.forEach(function(user){ %>
  <p class="secret-text"><%=user.secret%></p>
<% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering undefined value to usersWithSecret, assign "foundUser" to  "usersWithSecret".
`res.render('secrets', {usersWithSecret: foundUser});`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/secrets", function (req, res){
    User.find({"secret": { $ne: null }})
    .then(function(foundUsers) {
      console.log(foundUsers);
      res.render("secrets", { usersWithSecrets: foundUsers });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
 
});
```

Comment: Please include an explanation for why and how this solves the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using **render** in another page
**for example:**

```
app.post("/submit",function(req,res){
    res.render("secrets");
})
```

here we must use **res.redirect** instead of **res.render**.
like this:

```
app.post("/submit",function(req,res){
    res.redirect("secrets");
})
```